# How to run same function twice with different request.meta in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have one function which needs to be run twice with a different request.meta in scrapy

```
request = scrapy.Request(tournament_url, callback=self.parse_tournament)
request.meta['data'] = team1_data
yield request

request1 = scrapy.Request(tournament_url, callback=self.parse_tournament)
request1.meta['data'] = team2_data
yield request1
```

As of now, only the first request is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to include [`dont_filter`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.0/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) in your 2nd `Request` to avoid the Scrapy DupeFilter dropping the already-seen URL:

```python
request1 = scrapy.Request(tournament_url, callback=self.parse_tournament,
                          dont_filter=True)
request1.meta['data'] = team2_data
yield request
```